# Convert Float Properties to String in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I want to export data from GEE to my google drive. So for the name file I use information from its data properties. I resulted as this

`2019.0_1.0`

What I want is this

'2019_1'

This is my code

```
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(byMonthYear, 'sst', {
  name: '{year}_{month}',
  type: 'float',
  scale: 1000,
  region: POI
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ee.String(ee.Number(num).toInt())
could possible get what you want